# Shell Scripting -awk option help required

Tags: shell, unix, sunos

The script should read each file in the path and replace the string in each single row.How to create temp file and mv replace while i am iterating 10 diff input files name in the same path 
Pls advice

SunOS 5.10

```
FILES=/export/home/*.txt
for f in $FILES
do
echo "Processing $f file..."
cat $f | awk 'BEGIN {FS="|"; OFS="|"} {$8=substr($8, 1, 6)"XXXXXXXXXX\""; print}'
done
```

input file

```
"2013-04-30"|"X"|"0000628"|"15000231"|"1999-12-05"|"ST"|"2455525445552000"|"1111-11-11"|75.00|"XXE11111"|"224425" 
"2013-04-30"|"Y"|"0000928"|"95000232"|"1999-12-05"|"VT"|"2455525445552000"|"1111-11-11"|95.00|"VVE11111"|"224425"
```

output file

```
"2013-04-30"|"X"|"0000628"|"15000231"|"1999-12-05"|"ST"|"245552xxxxxxxxxx"|"1111-11-11"|75.00|"XXE11111"|"224425" 
"2013-04-30"|"Y"|"0000928"|"95000232"|"1999-12-05"|"VT"|"245552xxxxxxxxxx"|"1111-11-11"|95.00|"VVE11111"|"224425"
```

Not sure how use this

```
cat $f | awk 'BEGIN {FS="|"; OFS="|"} {$8=substr($8, 1, 6)"XXXXXXXXXX\""; print}' $f > tmp.txt && mv tmp.txt $f
```

Comment: When you do `FILES=/export/home/*.txt`, you're actually storing the glob pattern itself, not a list of filenames. It's better to either not do that at all, or use a shell where you can store the result as an array.

Comment: fedorqui-pls edit in better way i need the answer

Comment: `cat <file> | awk ...` can be much better written as `awk ... <file>`.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what appears to be your desired end result you can use ***ed*** instead of ***awk***.

```
FILES=/export/home/*.txt
for f in $FILES; do
    echo "Processing ${f} file..."
    ed  "${f}" <<EOF
% s/\([0-9]\{6\}\)[0-9]\{10\}/\1xxxxxxxxxx/
w
q
EOF
done
```

This requires fewer steps (ie command calls) because you're not creating a temp file and moving it. Instead you're editing the file in place with the desired changes and then closing it.

```
% means "operate on every line" (don't worry about lines that don't match)
s means "perform a substitution" -- /[pattern]/[replacement]/
w means write
q means quit
EOF closes out the "here document"
```

Hope that helps.

Edit Note: [Charles Duffy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy) pointed out that ***ed ${f}*** would fail on files names with spaces in them and ***ed "${f}"*** would not suffer from that particular deficiency. This is true. <strike>It's also the case, however, that the **for** loop above would likely split on any spaces in the file names. You can set **IFS** (`IFS='\n'`) to get around this limitation on KSH, BASH, MKSH, ASH, and DASH. In ZSH (depending on your version) you may need to set SH_WORD_SPLIT. As an alternative you can change from a **for** loop to a **while** loop with **read**:</strike>

```
FILES=/export/home/*.txt
ls ${FILES} | while read f; do
    echo "Processing ${f} file..."
    ed  "${f}" <<-EOF
% s/\([0-9]\{6\}\)[0-9]\{10\}/\1xxxxxxxxxx/
w
q
EOF
done
```

Edit Note: My erroneous statements above stricken but kept for historical purposes. See comments from Charles Duffy (below) for clarification.

Comment: `ed "$f"` -- without the quotes, this won't work correctly on filenames with spaces.

Comment: ...err. Using `ls` adds its own, platform-specific problems with unprintable filenames, and using `read` without `-r` or a cleared `IFS` expands backslash sequences and clears trailing whitespace. Much safer to use `printf '%s\0' $FILES | while IFS='' read -r -d '' f`, if for some reason you couldn't do the Right Thing and use `for f in /export/home/*.txt`

Comment: ...and no, the for loop above **doesn't** split on spaces, because `FILES=/export/home/*.txt` doesn't expand the glob expression; it just stores it literally.

Comment: Again sir, you are correct.

Comment: I tried running the script FILES=/export/home/*.txt
for f in $FILES; do
    echo "Processing ${f} file..."
    ed  "${f}" <<EOF
% s/\([0-9]\{6\}\)[0-9]\{10\}/\1xxxxxxxxxx/
w
q
EOF
done with my input file but it didn't edited my input file .After running the script the input file remains same.I am not sure if this  script works or do i need to modify the pattern .I need the script to work to process the input data mentioned above.Pls help

Comment: @Sen Does your previous script modify the files appropriately? You can test the action by specifying just one file with the **ed** command `ed [[your filename]]` Then paste in the commands between ***<<EOF*** and ***EOF***. See if you get the desired result

Comment: @Cliff/Charles -I tried the script in bash/linux which is working fine but when i try the same with sunos/unix it is not working .Not seeing any error , the input file remains same .Pls advice